# checking if there is json obejct in ajax reply from server without crashing javascript

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, object, isset

UPDATE

Here Ajax receives some responseimage from the server

```
success: function(responseimage)
            { 
.....
}
```

This gets object and puts it into result variable.

```
 result = jQuery.parseJSON(responseimage);
```

**response image is always positive. It has always something inside**

Problem is that sometimes in responseimage there is no JSON object.

So how can I check it after getting result frmo server is there any object or not ?

```
if( result = jQuery.parseJSON(responseimage)) crashes script
if( typeof jQuery.parseJSON(responseimage)!='undefined') crashes script
```

Any other ways to check ?

Comment: Is `responseimage` null or undefined, or is there some other, non-JSON data stored there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In lieu of writing a more intelligent `tryParseJSON` function (one may already exist, I'm not sure), I would simply wrap the parse call in a try-catch block:

```
 try {
     result = jQuery.parseJSON(responseimage);
 } catch (e) {
     result = {}; // Or some default value
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result;

if (responseimage) {
    result = jQuery.parseJSON(responseimage);
}
```

Comment: responseimage is always positive. problem is that sometimes it has no JSON inside

Comment: can you give an example of what is returned without JSON?  is the same thing always returned if it is not JSON?